# css отображается некорректно, выводит только фон. а нужно чтоб выводило плитки

Tags: html, css

```css
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #9acd32 0%, #b2ec5d 100%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.slider-wrap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.slider {
  width: 100%;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
}

.slider-item {
  width: 530px;
  padding: 20px 0 25px 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 9px #f1f1f4;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.animation-card_image {
  max-width: 60px;
  max-height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 9px rgba(241, 241, 244, 0.72);
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.img {
  width: 53px;
  height: 53px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.animation-card_content {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 374px;
  margin-left: 26px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

.animation-card_content_title {
  color: #4a4545;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: -.18px;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin: 0;
}

.animation-card_content_description {
  color: #696d74;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.animation-card_content_city {
  font-size: 11px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #696d74;
}
```

```html
<hmtl>

  <head>
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="slider-wrap">
      <div id="card-slider" class="slider">
        <div class="slider-item">
          <div class="animation-card_image">
            <img src="" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="animation-card_content">
            <h4 class="animation-card_content_title">Mirror widget</h4>
            <p class="animation-card_content_description"></p>
            <p class="animation-card_content_city"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-item">
          <div class="animation-card_image">
            <img src="" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="animation-card_content">
            <h4 class="animation-card_content_title ">Mirror widget 2</h4>
            <p class="animation-card_content_description"></p>
            <p class="animation-card_content_city"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-item">
          <div class="animation-card_image">
            <img src="" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="animation-card_content">
            <h4 class="animation-card_content_title">Mirror widget</h4>
            <p class="animation-card_content_description"></p>
            <p class="animation-card_content_city"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-item">
          <div class="animation-card_image">
            <img src="" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="animation-card_content">
            <h4 class="animation-card_content_title ">Morror widget</h4>
            <p class="animation-card_content_description"></p>
            <p class="animation-card_content_city"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-item">
          <div class="animation-card_image">
            <img src="" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="animation-card_content">
            <h4 class="animation-card_content_title">Mirror widget</h4>
            <p class="animation-card_content_description"></p>
            <p class="animation-card_content_city"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: опишите проблему подробнее пожалуйста

Comment: А в чём некорректность? У меня отображается фиолетовый цвет)

Comment: Некорректность в том, что вы не написали что вы ожидаете от кода и что происходит на деле. Без этого вам не помогут.

Comment: Автор хотел сделать, наверное, что-то типа https://codepen.io/aford9880/pen/BaPEPXd. В общем, проблема вероятнее всего в классах slider и slider-item. Ну и код надо как-то дружелюбнее сделать

Comment: @aford сомневаюсь, ведь js не использовал Автор)). Скорее всего просто блочные элементы

Answer (score 1):

В общем вот, css у вас вообще не правильный, я его стёр и написал свой с нуля.

```css
:root {
  --width-gap: 30px;
  --width-four-blocks: calc(calc(100% / 3) - calc((var(--width-gap) * 2) / 3));
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #9acd32 0%, #b2ec5d 100%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.slider-wrap {
  padding: 15px;
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  gap: var(--width-gap);
}
.slider-item {
  width: var(--width-four-blocks);
  background: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 5px white;
  display: flex;
  gap: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.animation-card_image {
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  min-width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.animation-card_image img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.animation-card_content h4 {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<hmtl>

  <head>
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="slider-wrap">
      <div id="card-slider" class="slider">
        <div class="slider-item">
          <div class="animation-card_image">
            <img src="" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="animation-card_content">
            <h4 class="animation-card_content_title">Mirror widget</h4>
            <p class="animation-card_content_description"></p>
            <p class="animation-card_content_city"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-item">
          <div class="animation-card_image">
            <img src="" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="animation-card_content">
            <h4 class="animation-card_content_title ">Mirror widget 2</h4>
            <p class="animation-card_content_description"></p>
            <p class="animation-card_content_city"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-item">
          <div class="animation-card_image">
            <img src="" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="animation-card_content">
            <h4 class="animation-card_content_title">Mirror widget</h4>
            <p class="animation-card_content_description"></p>
            <p class="animation-card_content_city"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-item">
          <div class="animation-card_image">
            <img src="" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="animation-card_content">
            <h4 class="animation-card_content_title ">Morror widget</h4>
            <p class="animation-card_content_description"></p>
            <p class="animation-card_content_city"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-item">
          <div class="animation-card_image">
            <img src="" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="animation-card_content">
            <h4 class="animation-card_content_title">Mirror widget</h4>
            <p class="animation-card_content_description"></p>
            <p class="animation-card_content_city"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

  </html>
```